# Taylor series with accuracy of 0.00001 (prints same value as entered by user) C code

Tags: c, gdb, precision, taylor-series

Im trying to calculate the sin(x) using Taylor Series for sin x by formula with the accuracy of 0.00001 (meaning until the sum goes lower than precision of 0.00001).

(x is given by radians).

The problem is that my function to calculate sin (using Taylor series formula) is printing out the same value as given (for example if 7 is given it will print out 7.00000 instead of 0.656987).
tried to debug my code using gdb and couldnt figure out why it stops after first iteration.
Here`s my C code in order to calculate sin (x ) using Taylor series.

```
double my_sin(double x) {
  int i=3,sign=1; // sign variable is meant to be used for - and + operator inside loop.
// i variable will be used for power and factorial division
  double sum=x, accuracy=0.000001; // sum is set for first x.
for(i=3;fabs(sum) < accuracy ;i+=2){ // starting from power of 3.
    sign*=-1; // sign will change each iteration from - to +.
sum+=sign*(pow(x,i)/factorial(i)); // the formula itself (factorial simple function for division)
}
return (sum); 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `fabs(sum) < accuracy` why is this condition there? what is it supposed to do?

Comment: to limit for loop until sum goes lower than accuracy which is 0.00001 the fabs is just to protect from negative value during iterations.

Comment: Did you mean the absolute *change* in the sum?

Comment: (1) `sum` is your answer. you expect your answer to be `0.656987`. how is that number related to `0.00001`? (2) the condition of the `for` loop doesn't work this way. the loop is executed when the condition is true, and stops executing when it is false. since your condition starts from false, the loop is never executed.

Comment: (1) my answer for 7 suppose to be 0.656987 (according to sin(x) function by using the library math.h) thats the result for x=7 for sin(x). (2) i understand now why my loop is not executed but how i`m supposed to limit my sum with the precision of 0.00001. do i need to add an if  condition (fabs(sum-prevSum)<accuracy) then break?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes until it goes lower than accuracy then break from loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tried to debug my code using gdb and couldnt figure out why it stops after first iteration.

Well, let's do it again, step by step.

1. `sum = x` (input is `7.0`, so `sum == 7.0`).
2. `for(i=3; fabs(sum) < accuracy; i+=2) { ...`
   Since `sum` is `7.0`, it is not less than `accuracy`, so the loop body never executes.
3. `return sum;` -- `sum` is still `7.0`, so that's what your function returns.

Your program does *exactly* what you asked it to do.

P.S. Here the code you probably *intended* to write:

```
double my_sin(double x) {
  double sum = x, accuracy = 0.000001;
  double delta = DBL_MAX;
  for(int i = 3, sign = -1; accuracy < fabs(delta); i += 2, sign = -sign) {
    delta = sign * pow(x, i) / factorial(i);
    sum += delta;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! wanted to ask if  the condition inside for loop accuracy < fabs(delta) suppose to solve the problem ? and why you`ve added delta variable for calculation ?

Comment: @Ouzan You want to stop the loop once the `sum` changes by a value smaller than your desired accuracy. `delta` is the variable that records that change.